# testing for asymetry image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I need to test for asymmetry for an image using skimage.

So far, I've split the image into four quadrants, and was thinking to compare them to test the symmetry.

the function that turns them into quadrants is below.

```
def image_into_quadrants(image):
    nrows, ncols = image.shape
    rsplit, csplit = nrows // 2, ncols //2
    
    quadrants = [
        image[:rsplit, :csplit],
        image[:rsplit, csplit:],
        image[rsplit:, :csplit],
        image[rsplit:, csplit:],
        ]
    return quadrants
```

How could I compare and test for the asymmetry using the quadrant images?

Comment: How about: when you have a pixel (x, y) of an image (W, H), you might calculate the symmetry point and compare them one by one?

Comment: how would you calculate  the symmetry point?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you would want to compare halves rather than quadrants, if you want to know whether the left half is a mirror of the right or the top half is the mirror of the bottom.

With that in mind, I split an image into left-right halves, flipped the right half and compared. Then I split the image into top-bottom halves and flipped the bottom (about the other axis) and compared.

I calculated the symmetry so it falls in the range 0..1 as:

```
symmetry = intersection of pixels between halves / union of pixels between halves
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

def TestSymmetry(A, B):
    """Test the symmetry between two images by calculating the intersection/union of pixels"""
    intersection = cv2.bitwise_and(A,B)
    # DEBUG cv2.imwrite('intersection.png', intersection)
    union = cv2.bitwise_or(A,B)
    # DEBUG cv2.imwrite('union.png', union)
    res = cv2.countNonZero(intersection)/cv2.countNonZero(union)
    return res

# Read image in greyscale and get shape and centres
im = cv2.imread('image.png',0)
h, w = im.shape
ch, cw = h//2, w//2

# Test left-right symmetry
left  = im[:, :cw]
right = im[:, cw:]
LR = TestSymmetry(left, np.flip(right, axis=1))

# Test top-bottom symmetry
top = im[:ch, :]
bot = im[ch:, :]
TB = TestSymmetry(top, np.flip(bot, axis=0))
print(f'{int(LR*100)} {int(TB*100)}')
```

I then slid a square across another one and annotated it at the bottom with the results from the two different axes.

[image]

Hopefully you can see the Left-Right symmetry increases to 100% when the sliding square coincides with the static, central square. And also, that the Top-Bottom symmetry is always 100% because the top and bottom halves of the image are always symmetrical.

---

I just realised you wanted to use **skimage** rather than **OpenCV**. I trust you can translate it pretty simply, or use the 3 **Numpy** equivalents below:

```
intersection = np.bitwise_and(A,B)

union = np.bitwise_or(A,B)

res = np.count_nonzero(intersection)/np.count_nonzero(union)
```

---

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, skimage, scikit-image, OpenCV, symmetry, symmetrical, asymmetry, asymmetrical, intersection, union.